# Save files using php from a URL

Tags: php, codeigniter

So I have an URL, let's say `http://mysite-1.com/img.jpg` and I want to acces that URL with PHP from another site and save the file, I don't know from where to start, can you guys give me some tips? I'm using CodeIgniter and I want to use this with the `upload()` method, but any other method will also be appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A really, really simple method is:

```
copy("http://example.com/source.jpg","destination.jpg");
```

As long as `destination.jpg` is somewhere on your server, it'll get the image from the remote one and save it, just like you want.

Comment: +1, nice answer, didn't know that copy works with urls, expected file_get_contents/file_put_contents construction.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Really simple method, outstanding result.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming allow_url_fopen is enabled in your php.ini, you can access URLs remotely just like you do local files.

```
file_put_contents('/path/to/local/file', file_get_contents('http://domain.com/path/to/remote/file'));
```

Comment: Yeah, probably better to use copy.